# Exception no Selenium Webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testes-de-unidade

olá, estou tendo problema nesse ponto:
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Emitir Guia de Pagamento (DAS)"}
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a mensagem, ele não encontrou um link com o texto do elemento. Tente encontrar o elemento por outro tipo de localização, por exemplo: CSS, ID, Name.

1. Ao invés disso

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Emitir Guia de Pagamento (DAS)")).Click();
```

Tente isso:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("NameDoLinkDePagamento")).Click();
```

Ou isso:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ID("NameDoLinkDePagamento")).Click();
```

Ou também por uma parte do texto:

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Emitir")).Click();
```

2. Em alguns casos, quando a página possui scroll, é necessário posicionar o elemento em uma altura que facilite a "visualização" do elemento pelo chromeDriver. Você pode fazer isso, utilizando JavaScript, conforme abaixo :

```
var alturaPagina = 600;
var _script = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
_script.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0, alturaPagina)");
```

Comment: Shai, considere melhorar sua resposta, pois ela está muito "rasa" em termos de explicações/definições. Veja [como escrever uma boa resposta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)